# Xamarin.Forms iOS disable Frame animation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i am experiencing a strange behavior in Xamarin.Forms running on iOS.
I've got some custom controls where I change the size of a frame dynamically or make them visible during runtime.

When changing the size of the frame (via an AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds property) you can see, that the size change is significantly slower, that the rest of the UI. In addition to that, when making the frame initially visible, it's flying in from the bottom right corner of the device.

I've recorded the behavior to make it more clear:

[image: Visibility]

[image: Visibility & Dragging]

I was not able to find some docu on this animation behavior and it is not present on Android.

Is there a property to disable this animations, or can it be done via a custom renderer for iOS?

EDIT://
[I've added a git repo with code](https://github.com/daniel-streetec/XamarinFramesIssue)

Comment: Add code to question., as text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve thanks for your reply.
Sorry, i've added a repo to the question.

Comment: I tested your code, if the background in your custom control does not use LinearGradientBrush, no animation will appear. LinearGradientBrush is a brush types, when the control is loaded for the first time, it will draw an area so animation will appear, if you don't want the animation appears and you can customize the color in the background without using a LinearGradientBrush.